# runtime in Augmented Reality

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I'm working on an augmented reality app, I have models stored in a database, When I catch an ID from the camera view I want to go to the database and fetch the model who have relation with that ID at runtime.
In other words, how can I dispaly the virtual thing of AR at runtime?
halp me

Comment: are you using vuforia?

Comment: Your question is a bit confusing me, have you things running, have you done some work, which framework are you using?

Comment: @maytham-ɯɐɥʇʎɐɯ   
I just want to display the virtual stuff at runtime

Comment: you already imported the package that you can download from the page?, if yes, then there should be a target marker, where you can select the marker from your database, then attach you model to that target marker and thats all

Comment: @CristianCamG   yes i do

Comment: @CristianCamG Can this be done at runtime?

Comment: yes, the vuforia code is performed at runtime, when it detects your object the renderer turns on.

Comment: @CristianCamG  thank you, now i know what should i do :))